# jQuery niceScroll not working on Dynamic DIV

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, nicescroll

I've been struggling with this problem for weeks, and I've researched dozens of posts on this site and others. I have a very basic problem. I have a DIV tag `#scrollarea` that is created on the fly, destroyed and recreated on the fly several times in a single web app. My problem is that the niceScroll feature only works ONCE. After the second attempt, I no longer get the controls

I've tried several techniques including the `resize()` method, and nothing works. I've also installed a regulator that ensures that it's only installed once, and then `resize()`'d after that. Again, nothing works.

It's a very difficult thing to demonstrate here given that my code is locked behind secure doors, and it's triggered through scripts.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how this can be done? To review:

- page loads, no `#scrollarea` is present
- script fires, and the `#scrollarea` is installed into a `DIV`
- `niceScroll` is attached to `#scrollarea` ONCE and works PERFECT
- script fires again, `#scrollarea` is replaced by NEW scrollarea
- regardless of what technique I use, the scrollbars no longer work

Methods attempted:

- Install `niceScroll` each time the new `#scrollarea` arrives
- Install `niceScroll` ONCE and never again
- Install `niceScroll` ONCE and then issue a `getNiceScroll().resize()`
- Attempted the `.mouseover()` -> `.resize()` technique

All techniques fail to render a usable scrollbar on the second use.

Comment: please post some code, and link to the plugin

Comment: I have it maintaining now, but it's losing its visual configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE: new function found!**

```
 var setScroll = function(i) {
        if($(i).length>0)
        $(i).niceScroll().updateScrollBar();
}
```

Call this function to Update niceScroll

```
setScroll(".classWithNiceScroll");
```

---

-----*Old Method*-----

use this instead of resize

```
$("idORclass").getNiceScroll().remove()
$("idORclass").nicescroll();
```

Comment: upvote for old method, `updateScrollBar()` is not a function error. Version 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

> script fires again, #scrollarea is replaced by NEW scrollarea

What do you mean by that ? is your `#scrollarea` removed from the DOM, and a new one inserted ? or do you have its content replaced, like `$('#scrollarea').html( blabla )` ?

Have you tried `$(window).trigger('resize')` ? nicescroll seems to watch for resize events, but not for DOM changes.

Comment: Exactly. I have a version working now using resize() HOWEVER it's completely losing my configuration parameters. It turns into a white bar with gutters, etc. My configuration is the default settings with a slight increase in width. I think I'm going to ditch the dynamic technique and just ensure the #div is always present.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using an empty div that I could add dynamic content to when certain events were triggered, however, upon adding content, the scrollbar would not appear. I got it to work by prepopulating the scrollbar div with another empty div with a height that overflowed the div I had the scrollbar on.